# How to handle heavy API response in react native?

Tags: react-native, axios

**Issue Description::**

I'm working on react-native application. There are too many API data in my server. If I'm hit this API for the first time on the page, then it's working fine. But the app closes when hit API second time on same page. There is no error / crash log for this on the firebase.

I am using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for hit the API on server.

**Code::**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getSingleUser();
}

 async getSingleUser() {
   NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
       axios.get(`${api_URL}`)
           .then(response => {
               Toast.show("2");
               this.checkApiResponse(response.data.response);
       })
       .catch(error => {
           Toast.show(JSON.stringify(error));
       });
   });
}


checkApiResponse(response) {
   this.setState({ loading: false, refreshing: false });
   console.log(response);
}
```

**Error Logs::**

```
--------- beginning of system
2019-03-20 15:06:37.846 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23858/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.846 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23825/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.847 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/22442/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.856 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23825/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.885 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/22442/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.924 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23825/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.924 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/22442/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.973 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23825/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.987 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/22442/oom_score_adj; errno=2
2019-03-20 15:06:37.989 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23107/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.989 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/22296/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.989 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/24137/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.990 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23642/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:37.990 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/23825/oom_score_adj; errno=2
2019-03-20 15:06:38.009 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23107/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.009 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/22296/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.010 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23642/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.020 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23107/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.020 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23579/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.021 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/24137/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.021 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23642/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.045 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/23579/oom_score_adj; errno=2
2019-03-20 15:06:38.723 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23148/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.726 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/19742/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.731 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/23148/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.760 1588-1800/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=632, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
2019-03-20 15:06:38.765 555-555/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/22716/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-03-20 15:06:38.786 743-743/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
2019-03-20 15:06:38.817 1588-1800/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=627, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
2019-03-20 15:06:38.850 1588-1779/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '347cfde com.miui.home/com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-03-20 15:06:39.579 24915-24915/? E/miuisdk: got ModuleLoadException when load modules: no such module found: com.miui.personalassistant
2019-03-20 15:06:39.820 743-743/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
2019-03-20 15:06:40.366 24931-23888/? A/google-breakpad: Microdump skipped (uninteresting)
```

Some time it's working fine, if API data is too small. This is a problem when API data is too large. Please suggest If anyone having a solution?

Comment: please share error log from app

Comment: There is no generating any erro logs.

Comment: open android studio and you'll find error logs in logcat. make sure your device is connected with machine.

Comment: Its create a problem in release build.

Comment: It could be the other issues rather than the API data size. You can mock the data response from your local and check if it still crashes.

Comment: Can you explain me what do you mean by mock the response, and there is no crashes when I am running this locally. I am having an issue on release build.

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora Can you share the full component code? How do you call 'getSingleUser' on second time? If you can share more details that would help!

Comment: hope things like this may help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpack

Comment: or just slice huge api into pages

Answer (score 1):

As @Maneesh said, this may be caused by the function being called multiple times without waiting for a response.
You mentioned you already have added a timeout to Axios, but there's a [known issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/647) that simply adding a timeout to Axios doesn't work. *(I've had this issue myself in the past)*

There's a workaround to set a timeout on an request - manually abort the request using a `cancelToken` and a normal javascript `setTimeout()`

```
function setRequestTimeout(source, timeout) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    source.cancel('timeout')
  }, timeout);
}

function getRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const timeout = 10000

    let source = axios.CancelToken.source()
    setRequestTimeout(source, timeout)

    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/your-address/', {
        timeout: timeout,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        cancelToken: source.token
      })
      resolve(response)

    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
}
```

This has worked for me in the past, my solution is derived from the comments found in [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/647) issue I've mentioned before, hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks @Lucas Dolsan, I have implemented this, but issue is not solve. There is not problem to hit the API, Problem is read json data. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24134

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to before getting response from api it is calling the function because as you mentioned for large size it is not working and I am not able to see `await` in your code. Try to add `await` to your `axios` and check. Hope this help you.

Comment: I am try `await` with `fetch`(await fetch(url)), but still its not working.

Comment: try to add timeout to axios

Comment: Try in increase the time for that